# Missing Save dialogs in Ubuntu 22.04 on a 2012 MacBook Pro

Tags: nautilus, filesystem, filemanager, appmenu

The application window becomes gray. If I press Enter a file is saved in the default location. It happens in all of the applications that I've tested. I tried installing xdg-desktop-portal-gtk. The results state that the latest version is installed, but there's still no dialog box.